# smbpasswd: Failed to add entry for user

Tags: debian, ldap, samba, pam

**tl;dr** Assuming a basic (but functioning) LDAP/PAM configuration, how come smbpasswd fails with this error message when I try to add an existing UNIX/LDAP user to Samba?

---

I have a basic, but working LDAP setup on a Debian server which has few accounts loaded with passwords and such, and their corresponding UNIX accounts have been created. I also have a basic PAM/NSS configuration which seems to be working.

I can login and use the accounts via LDAP. Now I want to configure a simple file share using Samba and have it authenticate users via the PAM/LDAP backend. I am at the point where I need to create Samba users using the `smbpasswd` utility, however this results in an error.

First, I set the LDAP password:

```
# smbpasswd -W
```

Then I tried adding a user which is already configured in LDAP:

```
# smbpasswd -a new_user
New SMB password:
Retype SMB password:
Failed to add entry for user new_user.
```

So I don't know why this command is failing. At first I figured it was because I needed to make the users in the LDAP directory be `sambaSamAccount`s. So I updated my user's LDIF file to look like this:

```
dn: cn=new_user,ou=group,dc=example,dc=com
cn: new_user
gidNumber: 1000
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixGroup

dn: uid=new_user,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: sambaSamAccount
uid: new_user
uidNumber: 1000
gidNumber: 1000
cn: test user
sn: new_user
mail: new_user@example.com
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/new_user
sambaSID: 3000
sambaDomainName: TEST-ROME
```

The only changes made to the above LDIF were the additions of `sambaSamAccount` as an `objectClass` and `sambaSID` and `sambaDomainName`. Eventually I want to implement a PDC, so I am pretty sure I need a `sambaSamAccount` anyway.

However, after all that I still get the same error.

So how can one debug this error?

---

**SOLVED** After debugging the daemon as suggested, I found that `smbpasswd` was executing queries with an empty `base dn` field, thus returning no results. This was fixed by adding the `ldap suffix` and `ldap user suffix` fields into my `smb.conf`. After that I realized I needed a correct way to generate sambaSIDs as well, but that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the best way to debug this issue is to see what's happening from the point of view of LDAP.  Firstly do a "ps aux |grep slapd" to get the arguments being passed to the daemon, on my system (CentOS 5.6) I get:

/usr/sbin/slapd -h ldap:/// -u ldap

Stop the slapd daemon (/etc/init.d/slapd stop or similiar) and then run the daemon interactively (i.e. from the command line) using the "-d" flag.  -1 (as an argument for -d) is a good starting point, i.e. it logs everything, i.e.

/usr/sbin/slapd -h ldap:/// -u ldap -d -1

If this is too much info, read up on the parameters to "-d" - from memory I used 256 quite a bit.  The idea is to get slapd giving some useful output and then replicate the problem.  You may get some useful output which is showing where things are going wrong.

Comment: Ok I'll try that, but shouldn't samba be logging something for this? That is, shouldn't samba have a more detailed explanation of why smbpasswd is failing?

Comment: Quite possibly :-)  However, my experience is that Samba tends to through some vanilla exception "NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED", e.g. - looking at the actual LDAP queries and result/errors that slapd is providing was the best option for debugging.

Comment: I think I noticed this before, but I am looking at some of the SRCH output, and I see that the `base` field is empty. For example `SRCH base="" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(uid=androadm)(objectClass=sambaSamAccount))"`. Shouldn't that `base` field have my base dn like `dc=example,dc=com`?

Comment: Ok, to answer my own comment, manually running a search both with and without the base dn replicates the problem. If I search with `base=""`, no results are returned (can't find the user in LDAP), but when I specify the base dn manually (`base="dc=example,dc=com"`) it works fine. Note I didn't get `smbpasswd` working yet, but I think I've identified a problem. I replicated this by using `ldapsearch` and watching the log. Somehow I need to figure out why `smbpasswd` is searching with a null base dn.

Comment: Ok, continuing on my little thread here, I added the `ldap suffix` and `ldap user suffix` options to smb.conf, and it's moved a bit further. Now I am getting a different error that I think is related to my users LDAP entry, but the point was that by not specifying the `ldap suffix` options, `smbpasswd` ended up executing queries with empty `base dn` fields, thus returning no results.

Comment: Excellent - great to learn that the output from slapd was useful in being able to troubleshoot the issue :-)

Answer (score 6):

Just Add the User into your local login User

For Ex :

## useradd smbuser

## smbpasswd -a smbuser

Then only you can able to add the user as samba user